# system out of exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, msbi

i am getting system out of exception while running ssrs report.my dataset contains this query..does any1 has any idea regarding this error?

TIA

**query in dataset:**

```
select sum(actual_amount_lcy) as actual_amount_lcy,sum(Actual_Amount_GCY) as actual_amount_gcy,  dgl.GLID_SK,fcta.rulecode,dgl.GL_Account_Code,dgl.[From Cost Centre],dgl.[To Cost Centre], fcta.Sales_Channel_SK,isnull(SC.Sales_Channel_Code,'') Sales_Channel_Code,fcta.Location_SK,isnull(lsf.Location_Code,'') Location_Code
,fcta.Company_SK,fcta.Customer_SK,isnull(csf.Customer_Code,'')Customer_Code,isnull(csf.Customer_Name,'') as [Customer Name],  fcta.Material_SK,isnull(dm.Material_Item_code,'') as Material_Item_code,isnull(dm.Material_Item_description,'') Material_Item_Description,isnull(dm.Material_Brand_Code,'') Material_Brand_Code,isnull(dm.Material_Brand_Description,'') as Material_Brand_Description,isnull(dm.Material_Sellingst_Code,'') as[Material Selling state code] ,isnull(dm.Material_Sellingst_name,'') as [Material_Selling_state_Name],isnull(dm.[Material Category Name],'') Material_Category_Name,isnull(dm.Material_Packtype_level_1,'') as MAterial_Packtype_level_1
,sum(Actual_Amount_LCY) amount,isnull(sdd.name,'') as sales_channel_name,dc.Currency_Code,stc.company_name,stc.business_unit,stc.country_name,
year(fy.TimeDate) as Year,Month(fy.TimeDate) as Month


from FCT_Value_Management_Actual fcta with(nolock)
inner join DIM_General_Ledger dgl with(nolock) on fcta.GLID_SK = dgl.GLID_SK 

left outer join DIM_Material DM  with(nolock) on dm.Material_SK = fcta.Material_SK and fcta.Company_SK = DM.company_id

left outer join DIM_Sales_Channel SC with(nolock) on SC.Sales_Channel_SK = fcta.Sales_Channel_SK and fcta.Company_SK = sc.company_id
left outer join stg_dim_dimension08 sdd with(nolock)  on sdd.code =  SC.Sales_Channel_Code and sdd.company_id = SC.company_id

left outer join DIM_Customer_ShipTo csf with(nolock) on csf.Customer_SK=fcta.Customer_SK and fcta.Company_SK = csf.company_id
left outer join Setup_Company stc with(nolock) on sc.company_id = csf.company_id

left outer join DIM_Location_ShipFrom lsf with(nolock) on fcta.Location_SK = lsf.Location_SK and fcta.Company_SK = lsf.company_id

left outer join DIM_Financial_Year fy with(nolock) on fy.TimeKey = fcta.PostingCalendarID 
left outer join DIM_Currency dc with(nolock) on fcta.Currency_SK = dc.Currency_ID 

where fcta.company_SK in(1,2,3) 

group by dgl.GLID_SK,dgl.GL_Account_Code,fcta.Sales_Channel_SK,SC.Sales_Channel_Code
,fcta.Company_SK,fcta.Customer_SK,fcta.Material_SK,dm.Material_Item_code
,csf.Customer_Code,fcta.Location_SK,lsf.Location_Code,
DM.Material_Sellingst_name, dm.Material_Packtype_level_1,dm.Material_Brand_Code,dm.Material_Brand_Description,
year(fy.TimeDate) ,Month(fy.TimeDate) ,dgl.[From Cost Centre],dgl.[To Cost Centre],sdd.name,csf.Customer_Name,DM.Material_Item_description,DM.Material_Sellingst_Code,DM.Material_Sellingst_name,DM.[Material Category Name],fcta.rulecode
,dc.Currency_Code,stc.company_name,stc.business_unit,stc.country_name
```

Comment: Please paste the total exception

Comment: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: I would suggest, get latest of your solution and by cleaning rebuild. Also, do iisreset once. It will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This depends exactly on when the error is generated and whether you are running this report on your local machine or an SSRS server, but essentially you are running out of physical memory to execute the report.  See [Microsoft KB Article for the error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909678).

Assuming a valid query and no rogue cross-joins:
1. Increase physical RAM.
2. Upgrade to 64-bit SSRS

Without knowing the structure of your database tables, it's hard to parse through that query of yours and make assumptions to determine if you are achieving the optimal execution. I would suggest though, that the query is probably the piece that needs refactoring.